# Can't login to domain as Administrator on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, administrator, domain

I am trying to decrease user account rights on a computer running Windows 7 pro newly added to a domain.  I connected to the domain fine, and when I tried to install software I got the "need Administrator password" dialog box.  I was able to input the domain administrator password and install software several times.  However, when I try to log into the domain using the administrator username and password, it says the username and password are not valid.  I  have tried several times to no avail.  The main software I want to install needs to have minimal user control, and the only way I can reduce it is with administrator privileges.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you logging in with "domain\username"?  And if you're using a domain account, and have tried several times, did you lock out the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `administrator` in the username field on Windows 7, it switches to the local administrator. Make sure you're putting `<DOMAIN>\administrator` in the username field.

Comment: You sir (or ma'am) get the gold star!!  Thank you.